# In numbers with range of values, how to move the decimal point left until a single digit integer remains in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rounding

I'd like to take a number like: 12345678 and turn it into 1.2345678, leaving only a single digit integer and whatever decimal.

Multiplying 12345678 by 0.0000001 works for the above example, but not if the number is 1234. The numbers change so a static multiplier will not work.

Is there a method available that would help? Bonus if it can be done within a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.log10` and `astype(int)` to find the correct power:

```
df['number'] /= 10**(np.log10(df['number']).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
     number
0  1.234568
1  1.234000
```

Answer (score 0):

Take below dataframe for example:

```
In [1192]: df 
Out[1192]: 
          a
0  12345678
1      1234
```

You can use Python's basic [`string slicing`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-slicing-in-python/):

```
In [1190]: df = df['a'].astype(str).str[0] + '.' + df['a'].astype(str).str[1:]

In [1191]: df
Out[1191]: 
             a
0    1.2345678
1        1.234
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think on two ways.

```
A= Str (xxxxxxx)

B = float (A[0]+”.”+A[1:len(A)])
```

Another way:

```
A=A / pow(10,len(str(A)-1)
```